# what is bundle installation script and its sole purpose in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

what is bundle installation script in netsuite and its purpose. I tried it to 
Suite Answers but could not figure out. Any help regarding to topic will be valuable.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only two cases where I have seen it used.

1. To use it as part of license management. A bundle installation script can check with a third party system to check if the account where the bundle being installed has a valid license.
2. To check if the features that your bundle needs is activated or available in the account it is being installed on.

Comment: We have also used it to initialize configuration data specific to that customer, overwriting the default values.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle installation script can also be used for data migration, when the bundle is updated. ie Suppose in the newer version of the bundle, you are adding one new custom field. For the existing custom records in the customer account, if you want to default that custom field to a particular value, after the bundle update, then you can do the same via bundle installation script (Using the afterInstall hook)